# Shuffling a GameBoard of the 1-15 or "Jigsaw" puzzle game (Android)

Tags: java, android, shuffle

I am a beginner android developer and I am working on creating a puzzle game called "Jigsaw".

Here is a sample screenshot of the main gameplay screen:

[image]

What I want to do is in the onCreate method call another method called shuffleGameBoard():

```
 public void shuffleGameBoard(){
    gameGrid.removeAllViews();
    GameBoard.scrambleBoard(gameBoard);

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            switch(gameBoard.getBoardValues()[i][j].getValue()){
                case 0:
                    gameGrid.addView(blankButton, index);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    gameGrid.addView(oneButton, index);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gameGrid.addView(twoButton, index);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    gameGrid.addView(threeButton, index);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    gameGrid.addView(fourButton, index);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    gameGrid.addView(fiveButton, index);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    gameGrid.addView(sixButton, index);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    gameGrid.addView(sevenButton, index);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    gameGrid.addView(eightButton, index);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    gameGrid.addView(nineButton, index);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    gameGrid.addView(tenButton, index);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    gameGrid.addView(elevenButton, index);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    gameGrid.addView(twelveButton, index);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    gameGrid.addView(thirteenButton, index);
                    break;
                case 14:
                    gameGrid.addView(fourteenButton, index);
                    break;
                case 15:
                    gameGrid.addView(fifteenButton, index);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

This method calls another method in my GameBoard.java class called scrambleBoard:

```
public static void scrambleBoard(GameBoard board){
    Random gen = new Random();
    int count = 0;

    while (count < 100){
        int i1 = gen.nextInt(4);

        int j1 = gen.nextInt(4);


        if (isValidSwap(board.getBoardValues()[i1][j1], board.getEmptyLoc(board))) {
            board.swapTile(board.getBoardValues()[i1][j1], board.getEmptyLoc(board));
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the issue I am having now: The instance of my GameBoard class that I used in my MainActivity.java is being properly shuffled. The mechanics of swapping tiles in my game work according to how the actual underlying GameBoard instance is shuffled. The problem; however, is that the actual buttons representing the instance of my GameBoard class are not displayed in the proper order at all. This is an image of what the board looked like after I called shuffleGameBoard(). It appears as if all the buttons are just in order from 1-15, but really they are being treating as if they aren't even though they look like it. For example, say that the board was shuffled so that the "two" tile ended up next to the "blank" tile. I could click on the "two" tile and it would still swap with the empty tile. The locations of the tiles would be swapped, but the tiles were not in the proper location in the first place so it is not working properly.

To clarify: When I am adding the views (ImageButtons) back into my GridLayout, they are not being displayed in the proper order. What can I do to add my ImageButtons into my GridLayout in the proper order, proper order meaning the order of the numbers in the instance of the shuffled GameBoard class that I am using in my MainActivity.java class.

I hope that my question was clear, if anything is unclear please ask for more information or clarification and I will happily provide. Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Try to use `GridLayout.LayoutParams` for every child instead of index. Like this for item in (1,3): `<GridLayoutInstance>.addView(<child>, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(1), GridLayout.spec(3)))`

Comment: @Valentin : Thank you for the tip, however, I just tried your solution and I am still getting the same issue with behavior.

Comment: Then i can only suggest drawing items instead of using View framework. I had a load of bad experience with it, especially involving dynamic content.